# SQL Server Find Duplicate dates with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I have a table that holds the following...

```
[uniqueID] [requirementId] [number] [description] [dtmexecuted] [amount]
```

I need to find all of the rows that have the same requirementid and dtmexecuted.  I tried

```
select 
    requirementid, dtmexecuted, count(*) 
from 
    [MyTable]
group by 
    requirementid, dtmexecuted
having 
    count(*) > 1
order by 
    requirementid
```

but that did not get me the results I need.  Here is an example of what I need.

```
[FEE55DE4-F7AD-438F-83F5-0002C7DAF993] [3719D29C-8532-4128-BECA-F720106AE61B] [03] [desc] [2011-04-01 00:00:00.000] [900.00]

[BRW46DE4-F1GC-125C-51RC-3985G7CFF873] [3719D29C-8532-4128-BECA-F720106AE61B] [04] [desc 2] [2011-04-01 00:00:00.000] [1900.00]
```

I need to write something that will return those two rows as having the same requirementid and dtmexecuted.

Comment: I dont see any reason for your query to fail, are your you are testing properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to return the rows, then you want to use a window function:

```
select [uniqueID], [requirementId], [number], [description], [dtmexecuted], [amount]
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by requirementid, dtmexecuted) as cnt
      from MyTable t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: but first thing is why will original query fail??

Comment: @loki: original query fails is because of GROUP BY, Using group by returns only 1 row for each (requirementid,dtmexecuted )

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual way I would tackle this problem.

```
select
  dest.*
from
  (
  select 
    requirementid,
    dtmexecuted,
    count(*) as RowCount
  from [MyTable]
  group by requirementid, dtmexecuted
  having count(*) > 1
  ) sub
  join [MyTable] dest 
    on dest.requirementid = sub.requirementid
    and dest.dtmexecuted = sub.dtmexecuted
order by requirementid, dtmexecuted
```

you can you CTE or Table variables to do it as well...